# bash script to get MAC address and paste it to ifconfig file after HWADDR

Tags: bash, awk, ifconfig, mac-address

Is there a way to get the MAC address from `ifconfig` and append after `HWADDR` in `ifconfig-eth0` file? I have used `awk` command to show MAC address but couldn't figure it out to hold that information and paste it to `ifconfig-eth0` file.

Comment: May I ask what the goal is ? Spoof the MAC address ?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than parsing the output of ifconfig (which might not even be installed by default) you should just set the variable from the contents of the /sys data:

```
MACADDR=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
```

Then you can just

```
echo “HWADDR=$MACADDR” >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

This is assuming you don’t already have a line with HWADDR, otherwise you’ll need to use sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get MAC address of eth0 with:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'
```

where:
`ifconfig eth0` displays only given network device

`awk '/ether/ {print $2}'` seeks 'ether' and prints second column in matching line

--

What is *ifconfig-eth0 file*?

ed:
former `$ ifconfig | awk '/^eth0/ {getline;print $2}'` was actually right only for not connected eth0, so proper one is now above.

Comment: the OP asked for MAC ADDRESS you command is giving me the IP.

Comment: It's giving mac address. My result is `00:1c:XX:XX:XX:XX`. It doesn look like IP. Ipv4 would be something like `192.168.1.15` and IPv6 `fe80::21c:XXX:XXXX:XXXX`. (these are my areal addresses so I "obfuscated" them a bit). It gives exactly the same result as `$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address`. Check it yourself.

Comment: not on my kali... ifconfig | awk '/^eth0/ {getline;print $2}'
10.0.2.17

Comment: so what `$ ifconfig eth0` shows? Give me full terminal dump - it's 7 lines.

Comment: lets head over to the chat so we are no ruining the comment section with our debug. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/103775/room-for-banjosa-and-tansy

Comment: Thanks to @BANJOSA it's been corrected and should work with every device now.

Comment: collaboration is always nice :) thanks for you time in troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command  and it worked fine

```
k=`ifconfig -a |awk '/HWaddr/{print $NF}'`
sed -i "/HWADDR/s/=.*/=$k/g" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```